# form keeps adding value a to session array on refresh?

Tags: php

i have a form on a page with a hidden input with the name of a book and a submit button i use to add the book name to an an arry contanined in the $_SESSION array. each time the user clicks on the button  the name of the book is added to the array contained in the session.this works fine. the main problem is when i refresh the page it the name of the book to the array again without me pressing the "add to cart button" i can see why this is happening as when i send the value to the array in an if statement i make sure and unset() the submit button. here is the code for the php part.

```
 <?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
   {
      if(!isset($_SESSION['itemnames']))
      {
        $itemnames = array();
        $_SESSION['itemnames'] = $itemnames;
    echo "<p>second if</p>"; 
      }
      if (isset($_GET['submit1']))
      {
       $name = $_GET['book1'];
       $_SESSION['itemnames'][]= $name ;
       unset($_GET['submit1']);
       echo "<p>" . var_dump($_SESSION['itemnames']) . "</p>";
      }
   } 
?>
```

and here is my form  i also have another form on the page and im wondering if this is causing the problem i dont think so at the moment.

```
<form method="get" action="" name="myform">
    <span style="color:#000">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
    </span>
    <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
        <option value="1" selected>1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="book1" value="cape clear island: its peopleand landscape"
    />
    <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="submit1">
    </button>
</form>
```

i cant think why refreshing  the page will add one to my array! im adding the name numerous time just to test will the multiple clicks work. thanks for your help in advance! obviously ill be doing other stuff with the dropdown list when i get this part working.
what i basically have is a submit button on a page that i should be able to click multiple times to add a book to a session array depending on how many times i want to add the book to the cart this will increment a counter at the top of the page depending on how many times the item is clicked. i just dont want the book to increment in the session array when i refresh. so the add item to cart button does not redirect the user to the cart im going to have a seperate button to "view cart" if you get what im trying to do here.

Comment: Do you have `?submit1=` in the URL which you are refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `POST` method for a form of this nature to help avoid problems like this.

Either way (`GET` or `POST`) you should issue a [`303 See Other`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) HTTP status code after you have handled the form submission, and redirect the user to the original page.

For example:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit1'])) {
  // Add the item to the array
  $_SESSION['itemnames'][] = $_GET['book1'];
  // Redirect and exit
  header('HTTP/1.1 303 See Other');
  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  exit;
}
```

In the above example I have used the `Referer:` header to determine where to send the user. This is not necessarily the best approach, as the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) states:

> Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

However, since I know nothing of the way you site is structured I have used this, since it will work correctly 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use post instead of get, its still in the url so it will insert to session again

EDIT: based on comment i now see what OP wants, so maybe this will help

to check if it's alredy sumbited you will have to handle that php side

```
if (in_array($name, $_SESSION['itemnames'])) {
    //its alredy there
}
else{
    //submit original code to insert
}
```

Comment: it doesn't matter if get or post...a request is a request, and on refresh it is sent again!

Comment: Your welcome, if you wish to use get to be able to insert from an url when not on page you could add that in php using the $_GET var but the form should really be POST, its much better.

Comment: now im getting a warning  inside in firefox which is a slight improvement but not what i want !"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."

Comment: @Sascha Galley, if you press f5 with a GET it will just input, if you have a request open using POST it will give a warning asking if you wish to insert again... if you say thats the same you need to be checked, when you go to url again after using POST it will NOT send again

Comment: i suppose i can get back to it later i need to figure out AJAX to get the value from the dropdown list to php! it does warn the user that it is going to resend the data wich is fair enough!

Comment: @MakuraYami in Firefox you can only cancel the request. The site won't reload. And furthermore, you rely on the user...bad idea!

Comment: how do i get the program to not allow the user to resend the data?

Comment: @eoin You need to redirect the user so that the URL in the address bar does imply a change in the server's state when it is loaded. See my answer.

Comment: OP never sayd anything about not ALLOWING the user to re-send it, he only asked how he coult prevent it from happening on refresh. now it's an entirely different question, ill edit my post

Comment: okay i dont want the user to be able to refresh the page! ive read about the double submit problem. anyone know a good tutorial in php that explains how to prevent it?

Comment: You cant prevent a user from submitting the same form again, thats all client side, you can only look at the data you get in php. and see if its alredy there and do nothing with it as my post explains